# if we have: $[(p_1)(p_2)(p_3)......(p_n)]+1$ & $p_n$ is the nth prime number, & $p_1,p_2...$ are all the prime numbers below $p_n$, is it always prime

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, prime-numbers

> if we have the following: $[(p_1)(p_2)(p_3)......(p_n)]+1$ where $p_n$ is the nth prime number, and $p_1,p_2...$ are all the prime numbers below $p_n$, is $[(p_1)(p_2)(p_3)......(p_n)]+1$ a prime number?

When i plugged in random numbers into the thing I thought that it was true but then obviously there are prime number generators on computers so it seemed as if $[(p_1)(p_2)(p_3)......(p_n)]+1$ shouldn't always be prime for a number $n$

How do i prove or demonstrate that $[(p_1)(p_2)(p_3)......(p_n)]+1$ isn't always prime?

Comment: What does your notation, $[(p_1)(p_2)] $, mean?

Comment: I think it is just multiplication, the $[]$ are probably redundant, maybe it seemed clearer to OP

Comment: Counterexample is a perfectly valid method. Try $n=6$.

Comment: $(2)(3)(5)(7)(11)(13) + 1 = 30031$. What are the factors of that?

Comment: I am sure Gregory knew $30031= 59 \times 509$ @infinitylord

Comment: A keyword for searching: primorial, actually made a mistake still the keyword is useful.

Comment: @infinitylord. Too many brackets. He means $(\prod_{j=1}^np_j)+1$.